# What is the meaning of the terms "buffer" and "window" in vim?

Tags: vim

Hi I'm new to vim and I don't know what buffers and windows are. I can't find any tutorials on how to understand these two, so here are my questions:

1. What is a buffer and how does it differ from a window?
2. What can the buffer used for? and the window (I'm assuming it's for editing only)?
3. Where can I find good tutorial on how to use buffers and windows?

Comment: [vim tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vim/info) has a lot of information to begin with.

Comment: It's a little obnoxious, but this image sums things up pretty well and is a factoid from the bot on the #vim channel on freenode: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=20gzol3&s=7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

does this answer your question?

```
   A buffer is the in-memory text of a file.
   A window is a viewport on a buffer.
   A tab page is a collection of windows.

A window is a viewport onto a buffer.  You can use multiple windows on one
buffer, or several windows on different buffers.

A buffer is a file loaded into memory for editing.  The original file remains
unchanged until you write the buffer to the file.
```

I think the best tutorial is vim's help file.

EDIT

the above help info you could find by `:help window`

Comment: I think you should note how to use the help, in this case `:h window` or `:h windows-intro` (deleted my answer).